# WCF Service no Endpoint

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-client

When I run WCF Test Client I get an error :

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from
>   localhost:52875/ControllersInfo.svc  If this is a Windows (R)
>   Communication Foundation service to which you have access,  please
>   check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified
>   address.
>   Metadata
>   contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 
>   localhost:52875/ControllersInfo.svc'. There was no
>   endpoint listening at localhost:52875/ControllersInfo.svc that
>   could accept the message.  This is often caused by an incorrect
>   address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more
>   details.

Here is my `web.config` file

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
    <services>
      <service name="dev_FineReceiptsService.ControllersInfo">
        <endpoint kind="webHttpEndpoint" contract="dev_FineReceiptsService.IControllersInfo" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="FineReceiptsTestEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/FineTest.csdl|res://*/FineTest.ssdl|res://*/FineTest.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=msdev01;Initial Catalog=FineReceiptsTest;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Can anyone tell me what I have done wrong ?

I tried to find similar question but none of them helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Your service is REST-based service (since you specified the `webHttpBinding`).

However, the WCF Test Client is a **SOAP-based** testing tool - you can test **SOAP** service with this - `basicHttpBinding`, `wsHttpBinding` etc.

But you **cannot** use the SOAP-based WCF Test Client to test your REST-based WCF service... that won't work. Use a regular web browser, potentially combined with Fiddler or something like that to test your REST services .

Comment: How I understand,I only tested Service wrong way,so I don't have error in Service, do I? Because in local browser works fine.

Comment: @Big.Child: you're definitely using a testing tool that **doesn't work** for your service. Whether your service has problems - there's no way for me to tell..... but you cannot use WCF Test Client against REST-based WCF services.

Answer (score 0):

Metadata endpoints expose WSDL + XSDs which describes **SOAP** services. There is no support for exposing metadata for REST. Since your are using webHttpEndpoint, you can not use WCFTestClient. For testing a Rest Service, [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) or Browser can be used.

If you need to add metadata to SOAP service with simplfied configuration you need to add this behavior:

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```